# Excel Macro copy paste in right till data in left cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have two excel columns in a worksheet, consider as A(left) and B(right) and I have recorded a macro where it will calculate a formula and copy/paste it to all the right side columns till where the left side column has data. but when next time some extra data is added to the left column and when I run a macro to copy/paste then it is only considering the previous range but not extending to the newly added cells.

example : A1:A5 is left side and B1:B5 is the right side and my formula in B range which is right range calculate based on A1:A5 and my macro works fine and restricted only to B1:B5 even when I added new data like A1:A10 only copying B1:B5. what is the method I can use my macro automatically till the data range of A side column?

Comment: Post your macro here so that we can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

As per your description just try below.

```
Sub FillFormula()
Dim i As Long
    i = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
        Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]+5"
        Range("B1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B1:B" & i)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Better next time, you provide a screenshot of your data & also VBA code in question.

You are using a static range, while you require is dynamic range.

try this

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Integer
i = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
Range("B1:b" & i).Select 'instead of selecting you can provide your formula to whole range.
End Sub
```

For any other issue, feel free to comment

Comment: it is just selecting the range but not copying the data.